# Why should I use MPI_REDUCE instead of MPI_ALLREDUCE?

Tags: mpi

I am *very* new to MPI programming (like two days old) and it is the first time I post a question on stack overflow. I am now dealing with `MPI_ALLREDUCE` and `MPI_REDUCE`. I understand that the difference between the two is that with the former the final value of the reduced variable is passed to all the processes, while in the latter case only to a target process. Even tough in many cases you do not need to pass the updated value of a variable to the child process I do not understand what are the benefits of not doing it (or doing it). I initially though it could be better to use `MPI_REDUCE` so that no computational time is wasted broadcasting the value of the variable, but I did not see any difference in the two cases in my code. I run the code with using a number of processes between 2 and 6.

The code takes a value `n`and the task of every process is to add 1 to the variable `mypartialsum`  `n/num_procs` times, where `num_procs` is the number of processes. After the reduction the values of `mypartialsum` are gathered in `sum` and the final result is `sum=n`.

```
program test
      use mpi
      IMPLICIT NONE
      !include 'mpif.h'
      integer:: ierr, num_procs, my_id, status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), sender(MPI_STATUS_SIZE), root, rank
      integer:: i, n
      !real:: sum=0., partialsum=0., mypartialsum=0.
      integer:: sum=0, partialsum=0, mypartialsum=0
      real:: starttime, endtime
      root=0

      call MPI_INIT ( ierr )
      call MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, my_id, ierr)
      call MPI_COMM_SIZE (MPI_COMM_WORLD, num_procs, ierr)
      starttime = MPI_WTIME()
      if (my_id .eq. root) then 
            print*, "Running in process 0."
            print*, "total numeber of process is", num_procs
            n=1d9!1000000000
      endif
      
      call MPI_BCAST(n, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      !print*, "running process", my_id
      mypartialsum=0.
      do i = my_id+1, n, num_procs
            mypartialsum=mypartialsum+int(1)
     
      enddo 
      partialsum=mypartialsum
      print*, "Running process", my_id, "Partial sum is ", partialsum
      call MPI_REDUCE(partialsum, sum, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
      !call MPI_ALLREDUCE(partialsum, sum, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

      endtime = MPI_WTIME()
      if (my_id .eq. 0) then
       print*, "sum is", sum, "time spent processing",  endtime-starttime
!      else if (my_id .gt. 0) then 
!       print*, "sum on process", my_id, "is", sum , "time spent processing is", endtime-starttime
      endif
     
     
      call MPI_FINALIZE ( ierr )
     

end program
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: there are no "child" processes in MPI. In your case you arbitrarily designate one process as the root of your collectives, but MPI is in principle symmetric: all processes are identical.

Secondly: your observation is correct: Allreduce runs in exactly the same time as Reduce.

So why do you need Allreduce? Because it is the common case in practice. Say you have a vector of billions of elements that is distributed over your processes. And it is too large to fit on a single process, which is why you use a distributed programming model. Now say that you want to normalize that vector. That means 1. calculate the norm with some sort of reduction, 2. make sure that every process knows that norm, so that 3. every process divides its own elements by that norm.

That sort of scenario is very common in scientific aplications, which is why I consider `MPI_Allreduce` to be the most basic collective routine.